# My is_unique rule is broke my validation in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm currently adding a create form with validation using a custom error message and the rule I want is required and is_unique but when I use the is_unique rule the validation just brake and the required rule doesn't call even though I fill it empty

This is my controller validation

```
public function create_admin()
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Create Admin',
            'validation' => \Config\Services::validation(), 
        ];

        return view('/admin/admin/create', $data);
    }

public function save_admin()
    {
        if (!$this->validate([
            'username_admin' => [
                'rules' => 'required|is_unique[admin.username_admin]',
                'errors' => [
                    'required' => 'Username perlu diisi',
                    'is_unique' => 'Username sudah ada'
                ]
            ]
            ]))
            {
                return redirect()->to('/admin/create')->withinput();
            }
}
```

**When I use only required rule (is_unique is deleted) it work

My AdminModel

```
class AdminModel extends Model
{
    protected $table            = 'admin';
    protected $primaryKey       = 'id_admin';
    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
    protected $allowedFields    = ["id_admin","username_admin"];
```

My create view

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/store" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?= csrf_field(); ?>
            <div class="form-list">
                <p>Username: <br></p>
                <input class="form-input <?= ($validation->hasError('username_admin')) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" type="text" name="username_admin" autofocus value="<?= old('username_admin'); ?>">
                <li><?= $validation->getError('username_admin'); ?></li>
```

if it error the form will turn red (if is_unique got deleted) when I fill it empty

I had to try to make my own is_unique rule but it doesn't work.